# iAd Network error - Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, iad

I am having this issue since I opened my `ITunes Connect` account last week. I have contacted Apple but I have not received any replay about this issue yet.

Is everyone else having the same issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it the first time you are using iAd?

Apple's response is this:

Your app version [new version] is currently under review and you enabled the app for iAd after [the prior version] was Ready for Sale. Your app name and other information will display the pending status until your app has been approved and Ready for Sale. This is also when your app will be eligible to receive paid ads from the iAd Network.

Answer (score 0):

With Refrence to this link You can get the answer 
[iAd FAQ](http:////https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/18.0.0.13.7.2.7.9.3.1.2.3.3.1.1.7.1)

After your app has been approved and is in the Ready for Sale state, it also will be reviewed by iAd to determine the app’s appropriateness for receiving ads from iAd advertisers. After your app has been approved by iAd, you can start earning revenue for ads that run in your app.